# Display a series of interfaces with one click of Run button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a program with around 40 interfaces which are to be displayed simultaneously. The code is as follows:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk(  )
root.title("8 Puzzle Game")

Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

def mainprg():

    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

    B.configure(command = mainprg1)

B = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Run", command = mainprg)
B.grid(row = 4, column = 1)



def mainprg1():
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

    B.configure(command = mainprg2)
def mainprg2():
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

    B.configure(command = mainprg3)
```

root.mainloop()

Here, i have to press the Run button each time to display the next interface. What should i do to display them simultaneously?

Comment: Do you want to display each one in a different window?

Comment: What do you mean *"simultaneously"*? Side by side? On top of each other?

Comment: Not in a different window. I want to display them one after another(like a slide show).

Comment: Rather than gridding ever-more labels on top of each other, why not retain references to them and change their text? This would make your code much more readable, `topleft.config(text="4")`, for example.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to tell.

Comment: @bio-terror at the moment, you create nine new `Tkinter.Label`s every time the interface changes. This seems a bit pointless; instead, you could keep references to the first set of labels, and update what they display as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "press the button once and then run them all in a row" you can do that by replacing

```
B.configure(command = mainprgX)
```

by

```
root.after(1000, mainprgX)
```

where X has to be replaced by the actual number.

This will at the end of each function trigger a one second timer to start the next one.

So the new code would be:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk(  )
root.title("8 Puzzle Game")

Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

def mainprg():

    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

    root.after(1000, mainprg1)

B = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Run", command = mainprg)
B.grid(row = 4, column = 1)



def mainprg1():
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

    root.after(1000, mainprg2)
def mainprg2():
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '4', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '8', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '3', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=1,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '2', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '5', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '1', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=2,column=3)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '7', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= '6', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Tkinter.Label(root, text= ' ', borderwidth=25 ).grid(row=3,column=3)

    root.after(1000, mainprg3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just accept the answer so everyone sees your question is solved.
You're welcome :)

Comment: Did you think about storing the contents for all slides in one 2D-Array? Could spare you some typing. just iterate over each one with a for-loop and you will just need 1 update fuction istead of 40.

Comment: Each interface differs with the previous one. The blank space is replaced by a number and vice-versa. So i couldn't think of how to iterate over them.

Comment: Well you use Strings to represent both: numbers and spaces, so it's no difference to python.